# Excel: What's causes an option to appear twice in a drop-down menu?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I am working on a budget and I have a drop down menu for the items. I have one category called Food but when I type in Food, it appears that there are 2 options

[image]

I can only select one of them and not the 2nd without getting an error. However, if I don't type and select from the drop down menu, I don't get any issues but it is tedious to select from the menu all the time and I have no issues for the other categories.

I found out this was the underlying problem of when I was trying to use `SUMIF` but kept getting 0 for food even though there were values for it. When I selected from the menu I started getting non-zero answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have one entry that has a space after the word Food.

To check that and find the culprit, create a helper column and use the Len() function to check the length of the cell. All cells with "Food" should have 4.  Find the one that has more characters and replace it with the correct entry.

Comment: If the space is unavoidable e.g. if the data is provided from external sources, I suggest using the =trim() function.